# Mask email regexp

Tags: php, regex, pecl

I 'm  tring to do a php regexp to mask a email so that

`example@gmail.com`  turn to `e*****e@gmail.com`.

```
$maskedEmail=preg_replace('/^*@/', '*', $email);
```

Comment: `preg_replace('~(^[^@]|(?!^)\G)[^@](?=[^@]+@)~', '$1*', $s)`

Comment: What if it's `john.doe@....`? Should it be `j**n.d*e@....` or `j*****e@....` or `j***.**e@....`?

Comment: @Andreas Just as importantly, what about `hi@gmail.com`?

Comment: True! Good point

Comment: I highly recommend using an online regex tester to test regex expressions before writing the full code.  One I use often is https://regex101.com.  There are many others, just google for onine regex tester.  It's an invaluable tool!  Also, when asking questions, it's recommended  to describe how what one's code does differs from what you are expecting it to do. (See the help pages for more info.) Including detailed information like this allows experienced users to *quickly*, and efficiently, hone in on the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~((?!^)\G|^[^@])[^@](?=[^@]+@)~', '$1*', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i7duJn/2)

**Details**

- `((?!^)\G|^[^@])` - Group 1: the end of the previous match or start of string and any char other than a `@`
- `[^@]` - a char other than `@`
- `(?=[^@]+@)`  - a positive lookahead that requires 1+ chars (that `+` is important here, you can't use `*`) other than `@` followed with a `@` immediately to the right of the current location.

The replacement is the value captured in Group 1 (so that the first char is kept in the string, and then all but the last char before a `@`  are replaced with `*`.

Answer (score 0):

To not mask the first character you could assert what is directly to the left is not the start of the string.

To not mask the character directly before the @, you could assert that what is on the right is always one character that is not an @ before matching it.

```
(?<!^).(?=[^@]+@)
```

In the replacement use:

`*`

**Explanation**

- `(?<!^)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not the start of the string
- `.` Match any character except a newline
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `[^@]+@` Match 1+ times any char except `@` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), and match `@`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omOS4a/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Qq13e)

For example

```
$email = "example@gmail.com";
$maskedEmail=preg_replace('/(?<!^).(?=[^@]+@)/', '*', $email);
echo $maskedEmail;
```

Result

> e*****e@gmail.com